# How many times has Alistair Cook been England's top scorer?

Tags: cricket

Does anyone know how many times (or equivalently, in what % of his innings) Cook has been England’s top scorer? How does that compare to the other players who have scored more than 10,000 runs in test cricket?

Comment: Asking for statistics about Cook is fine but asking about comparing him to other greats of the game makes this question too broad. Which players do you consider great. So, please edit the question & remove this second part of the question.

Comment: I've changed the question to have a quantitative (and reasonable) definition of "great".

Answer (score 1):

Cook has top scored in 58 of his 291 Test innings (19.9%).

All batsmen with more than 10,000 runs:

```
batsman         innings top-scorer  %
Tendulkar       329     78          23.7%
Ponting         287     46          16.0%
Kallis          280     51          18.2%
Dravid          286     53          18.5%
Cook            291     58          19.9%
Sangakkara      233     58          24.9%
Lara            232     65          28.0%
Chanderpaul     280     60          21.4%
Jayawardene     252     51          20.2%
Border          265     49          18.5%
Waugh           260     44          16.9%
Gavaskar        214     60          28.0%
Y Khan          213     48          22.5%
```

Comment: I'm in no way disputing the accuracy of this answer but it would be great if you could add the sources you used to determine this information.

Comment: Scorecards for international matches are freely available on various sites.

Comment: Sure. If you manually went through every scorecard of every match played by the 13 players above, then that's a heroic feat - I was hoping there was an easier way to do it...

Comment: It can be done programmatically if you first have all the relevant data in the right format.